# Init data from Ajax Request Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
Vue.component('config_input', {

template: '#config-input-template',

data() {
    paterns: []
},

computed: {
    testData() {
        return this.paterns;
    }
},

mounted() {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('/listPatern').then(function (response) {
        self.paterns = response.data;
    }
},

});
```

In the console show testData is an empty array. It means that inside success ajax request function the 'paterns' value didn't update yet.
Can anybody show me how to assign data response to 'paterns' value?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using axios for ajax in vue.

Unfortunately I wasted 3 hours because it did not matter what code I tried, the data was simply not being initialized.

I resorted to [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) and my code was working the first time!

Include the vue-resource library and change your mounted method like so:

```
mounted() {
    var self = this;
    this.$http.get('/listPatern').then(function (response) {
        self.paterns = response.data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could read [VueJS Tutorials](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html) carefully.

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data option, Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty. This is an ES5-only and un-shimmable feature, which is why Vue doesn’t support IE8 and below.
>
> The getter/setters are invisible to the user, but under the hood they enable Vue to perform dependency-tracking and change-notification when properties are accessed or modified. One caveat is that browser consoles format getter/setters differently when converted data objects are logged, so you may want to install vue-devtools for a more inspection-friendly interface.

The reactive data which VueJS do something like "proxy",thus you couldn't assign to value in Object.

```
// Wrong
self.paterns = response.data;

// Right
self.someObject = Object.assign({}, self.someObject, response.data)
```

And `data` should be a `Object`

```
data: {
    patterns: []
}
```

Comment: still got an empty array.